# Print whole lines, when find duplicate

Tags: awk, data-processing

This is fragment of my input:

```
DGD3 SOL10
DGD53 SOL15
DGD100 SOL15
DGD92 SOL20
DGD41 SOL22
DGD62 SOL35
DGD13 SOL40
DGD13 SOL40
```

My expected output

```
DGD53 SOL15
DGD100 SOL15
DGD13 SOL40
DGD13 SOL40
```

In my data I have sometimes SOL duplicates (not more than two repetitions not for example three times some SOL in a file but only duplicates). SOL is in my second column ($2). So I need a program which print whole line (DGD and SOL) when I find duplicate SOL ($2). Could you help me?

Comment: Are the duplicate always next to each other or could they be anywhere in the file?

Comment: Could be anywhere

Comment: @Mark then you should show that in your example as that requires a different solution to one that works when the lines are contiguous.

Comment: With GNU uniq: `uniq -f 1 -D file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another awk. Single run, no need for the file to be sorted, works correctly if there are more than 2 instances of the second field. In worst case it hashes the complete file in memory and produces no output:

```
$ awk '{
    if(!c[$2]++)           # if first instance of $2
        a[$2]=$0           # store it
    else {
        if(c[$2]==2) {     # if second instance 
            print a[$2]    # print previous
            delete a[$2]   # no need to waste my memory any more
        } 
        print              # after first instance of $2 we always print current
    }
}' file
```

Output:

```
DGD53 SOL15
DGD100 SOL15
DGD13 SOL40
DGD13 SOL40
```

Answer (score 4):

With your example as shown (SORTED by the second field) you can do:

```
$ awk 'l2==$2{print ll; print; next}
       {ll=$0; l2=$2}' file
```

Prints:

```
DGD53 SOL15
DGD100 SOL15
DGD13 SOL40
DGD13 SOL40
```

This is similar to the Unix `uniq` filter that only prints adjacent duplicates.

If the duplicates are random though the file, you can sort first:

```
$ awk 'l2==$2{print ll; print; next}
            {ll=$0; l2=$2}' <(sort -k 2 file)
```

Or, do a two pass over the file:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{cnt[$2]++; next} cnt[$2]>1' file file
```

Or, to just identify the SOL tags that are 2 or more, you could do:

```
$ awk '++cnt[$2]==2' file
```

And you could use that same method to generate command codes to either `grep` or `sed` to print from the file unsorted:

```
$ sed -n -f <(awk '++cnt[$2]==2 {printf "/[[:space:]]%s$/p\n", $2}' file) file
```

So the choice is:

1. to use more memory (by caching the entire file in memory keyed with the value of `$2`), or
2. sorting it first, or
3. traversing the file twice.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`, that will print duplicates **not necessarily adjacent ones**:

```sh
awk '$2 in map {print map[$2] ORS $0} {map[$2] = $0}' file

DGD53 SOL15
DGD100 SOL15
DGD13 SOL40
DGD13 SOL40
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding one more way in awkish style, where to get all value count in first read of Input_file and print all values as per their count in 2nd read. Fair warning this may not be fast as other 2 solutions but should be simple from understanding purposes.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  count[$2]++
  next
}
(count[$2]>1)
' Input_file  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

if your file is sorted in the second field `uniq` is designed for this task with the right options.

```
$ uniq -f1 -D file

DGD53 SOL15
DGD100 SOL15
DGD13 SOL40
DGD13 SOL40
```

skip first field, print all duplicates...