# Print 3x repetitions in second column in awk

Tags: awk

I want to print the whole line, when my program finds in the second column **exactly** 3x repetition. How to do that?

This is the input

```
DGD1 SOL401
DGD2 SOL4717
DGD2 SOL4847
DGD3 SOL401
DGD3 SOL4991
DGD3 SOL329
DGD4 SOL4991
DGD5 SOL4717
DGD5 SOL4717
DGD5 SOL401
```

This is the expected output

```
DGD1 SOL401
DGD2 SOL4717
DGD3 SOL401
DGD5 SOL4717
DGD5 SOL4717
DGD5 SOL401
```

Comment: process the file twice, first time use an associative array to keep a count, and second time print only if count is 3.. see https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ and search the awk tag for two file processing and similar questions to get started.. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a duplicate question as well

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Replace `>1` with `==3` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65542146/3776858) to a question from you.

Comment: Cyrus thank you so much. Sundeep thanks for the explanations. I write a comment in my script to learn how this script works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read the input file twice:

```
awk '
    { vals[$2] = vals[$2] $0 ORS }
    END {
        for (i in vals) {
            if ( gsub(ORS,"&",vals[i]) == 3 ) {
                printf "%s", vals[i]
            }
        }
    }
' eq9_1.ndx
```

Note that the above will work even for input coming from a stream.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
FNR==NR{
  count[$2]++
  next
}
(count[$2]==3)
' eq9_1.ndx eq9_1.ndx | tee test.ndx
```

I use this answer [Print whole lines, when find duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541539/print-whole-lines-when-find-duplicate/65542146#65542146) and change

```
count[$2]<1
```

to

```
count[$2]==3
```